# Ajax.ActionLink vs Html.ActionLink + Jquery.Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I can call an asp.net mvc controller via Ajax.ActionLink("Get customers","GetCustomers","Customer");

I can do the same with the Html.ActionLink and a jquery ajax call.

Where is the difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Where is the difference?

In the amount of code you have to write (less with Ajax.ActionLink) and the level of control you need (more with Html.ActionLink and a jquery ajax call).

So it's amount of code vs level of control and functionality needed => up to you to decide which one you need.

Both approaches are perfectly fine. The Ajax.ActionLink uses the jquery.unobtrisuve-ajax script to AJAXify the anchor behind the scenes.

Personally I always use Html.ActionLink + jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

No difference if you ask me `$.ajax` is what `Ajax.ActionLink` is using under the hood as @gdoron mentioned in his answer. Personally using `$.ajax` gives a more sense of control... you can manipulate more options available in `$.ajax` one plus point for `Ajax.ActionLink` is that i think it provides out of the box support of degradation if javascript is disabled never experienced it though but you can explore it...